# Displaying multiple feeds in different columns on the same page using simplepie

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

I am using simplepie to parse multiple rss feeds just fine and am able to put one on the html page. However I would like to add another or maybe two more to the html page. It would be displayed in a different column or box and pull from different rss feeds than the other. I am not sure if simplepie is able to do this, but I do not see any reason why it would not. I am fairly new to php and have researched but have found nothing that is useful. If anyone could point me in the right direction to find this out or even go as far as to post some coding, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the News Blocks demo or this [news.delic.com](http://news.delic.com)? This seems to demonstrate the functionality you're seeking.